# Spock invokes setProperty('x', 'test') instead of setX('test') on Mock object

Tags: groovy, spock

We have classes Foo and Bar:

```
class Foo {
    String x
}
class Bar {
    void call(Foo foo, String x) {
        foo.x = x
    }
}
```

In unit test we do:

```
void 'test' {
    setup:
    mockFoo = Mock(Foo)
    when:
    new Bar().call(mockFoo, 'test')
    then:
    1 * mockFoo.setX('test')
}
```

But in results we observe that test fails with "too few invocations" and shows that there was mockFoo.setProperty('x', 'test') call instead. This issue happens on CI environment. On local machine everything  is ok. Changing test to `setProperty('x', 'test')` leads to local fails. Can someone explain how to manage such issue?

Comment: what's the difference between local and CI?  Different groovy versions?  Different Spock version?

Comment: Only different java sdk. Both use 8 Java but CI uses amazon version. Local uses Open JDK

Comment: Spock 1.2, Groovy 2.4.10

Comment: Does it fail locally on the different JDK?

Comment: I do not think that the JDK makes any difference. I even installed Amazon Coretto JDK locally in order to make sure because I was curious, even though in disbelief. My guess is that, despite what you say, you do use any combination of different Groovy version, Groovy compiler, Spock version. If you have an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on GitHub for us including Maven or Gradle build configuration in order to reproduce the problem, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I recently fixed this bug in Groovy 3. Groovy 2.4 will still have the old behavior of using setProperty.

Also, indy vs default may make a difference in the instruction selection.

Comment: Do you have a link to the jira ticket?

Comment: I think it is one of these two.  It has been a while...  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-9385  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-8707

Comment: Possibly related to https://github.com/spockframework/spock/issues/1076 and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-9369

Comment: @emilles, sorry to dig this up, but I just ran this test on Groovy 2.5.14 after compiling with GrEclipse -Batch 2.5.12-02. It works fine on Windows and MacOS, but on Linux it callls `setProperty`. So it seems as if from Groovy 2.4 and 2.5 something was fixed, but somehow it is not working on all OS platforms. How is this possible?

Comment: I tried the example in Groovy 2.5.15, 3.0.9 and 4.0.0; it worked as expected, calling setX. It could work differently if the meta-property index is different or there is a SecurityManager in place. Hard to say just what is the cause for the difference. You can trace through ScriptBytecodeAdapter#setProperty for non-indy builds to see how “x” is resolved. For indy, it is a bit different but still based on the property index.

Comment: So that’s setGroovyObjectProperty in both cases. After that, cglib and JavaMockInterceptor (from Spock) take over. Spock checks the stack trace for ScriptBytecodeAdapter. So if your OS has a different stack, it could produce a different result.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but in my RSS feed there were not updates about your comments, which is weird. The bump from 2.5.14 to 2.5.15 does not fix the problem for me, still in all my GitHub builds on Linux the test reproducibly fails. Again, MacOS and Windows are OK. I use Spock 1.3, GrEclipse Compiler 3.7.0 and GrEclipse Batch 2.5.14-02. Can I contact you on another channel and point you to a reproducer project? Comments here doe not seem to be adequate to discuss this issue. P.S.: A local test on Linux Subsystem for Windows worked.

Comment: Look at [this build result](https://github.com/kriegaex/GebSpockSamples/actions/runs/1936967921), search the test logs for "failure!". One example is [this one](https://github.com/kriegaex/GebSpockSamples/runs/5430731565?check_suite_focus=true#step:10:3447). The test is [here](https://github.com/kriegaex/GebSpockSamples/blob/9d0eb89ab18e57fbc22c894d0b03afb96419e79e/geb-spock-samples/src/test/groovy/de/scrum_master/stackoverflow/q61065342/SetGroovyPropertyTest.groovy), and [this change](https://github.com/kriegaex/GebSpockSamples/commit/9d0eb89a) breaks it.

Comment: Cloning the project (feel free to fork), switching to branch `groovy-properties-emilles`  and running building with something like `mvn -am -pl geb-spock-samples test -Dtest=SetGroovyPropertyTest -DfailIfNoTests=false` should run the test. But like I said, I only see the problem on GitHub, not locally.

Comment: @kriegaex You can try with Groovy 2.5.16 now.  But I did mention above that a stack trace difference may be the reason for a difference on your OS.  JavaMockInterceptor from Spock is where you could debug/instrument or request an investigation from spock project.

Comment: I bumped Groovy 2.5.15 → 2.5.16, Groovy Eclipse Compiler 3.7.0 → 3.7.1. Same Linux problem in "your" branch. BTW, I also tried to bump Groovy Eclipse Batch 2.5.14-02 → 2.5.15-02, but then compilation fails with: _"The type groovy.transform.Generated cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files"_ BTW, why do you not publish on Maven Central and I need to add a JFrog plugin repo for more recent GrEclipse stuff?

Comment: Hm, GrEclipse Batch 2.5.15-02 did not like the fact that there were some `*.groovy` files in my `src/main/java` directory. Is that an intended change in GrEclipse? Because I created them there rather accidentally as Groovy classes I refactored them into Java ones, now compilation with GrEclipse Batch 2.5.15-02 works. But still no dice, the same property test [fails on Linux](https://github.com/kriegaex/GebSpockSamples/runs/5442194489?check_suite_focus=true#step:10:601).

Comment: The problem with stepping through the code is that I cannot reproduce the problem locally, it only happens during my GitHub CI builds on Linux. Do you have any idea what to log there in order to find out more?

Comment: OK, I added a test case capturing both `setX` and `setProperty`, stubbing the action to dump a stack trace. Here is a [diff screenshot](https://imgur.com/gallery/C0edV1Q) for you (right-click and "open image in new tab", if you want to see the image full screen).

Comment: You see that on Windows/MacOS, the Spock test calls `ScriptBytecodeAdapter.setGroovyObjectProperty`, while on Linux it calls `ScriptBytecodeAdapter.setProperty`. Both leads to `Collaborator$SpockMock$878190171.setProperty` calls, but on Linux the additional `ByteBuddyInterceptorAdapter.interceptNonAbstract` interceptor which leads to `Collaborator$SpockMock$878190171.setX` is not called as expected. Can you make anything of that? Would you see the reason in Groovy, in Spock or in the amalgam of both?

Comment: @emilles, because this affects Groovy 2.5.x which you are still maintaining, may I humbly request you to check my additional info and investigate further?